# Unable to log into new installation of macOS High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently installed macOS High Sierra on my MacBook Air. After that, it is not accepting the correct password. I also failed to unlock my FileVault. It also shows that the password I entered is wrong.

Later, I discovered that when I type it input some symbols instead of letters, I tried to change it using Input sources on the right most corner of the screen but again it’s not working.

I spend long hours for it, but all in vain. I decided to re-install macOS, and now the problem is I cannot boot from the USB. I tried all possible combinations to enter Disk Utilities, but in vain.

What should I do?

Comment: Before doing anything, Can you please try this link out? https://heresthethingblog.com/2014/08/25/mac-tip-restore-keyboard-default/

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about the installer, have you tested the hardware port?

- Do you have an external keyboard that you could use to see if that works?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and taking some time to contribute.  However, *Answers* are for posts that directly answer the question being asked.  If you need clarification, use comments.  Instead, rework this answer so it's not a follow on question, but an actual answer.

Comment: I’ll edit to show how it could stand alone. One hard thing is most questions involve some troubleshooting and asking the user tons of clarifying comments also doesn’t work well. Let’s flesh this out to be a real answer. Even if it’s a wrong answer for one case, it will be an answer for some that face this issue in the coming months.

Comment: Thanks bmike and Allan, I'll keep that in mind for future answers.